# For then - does it exist?

Tags: relative-clauses

Example:

The result is trivial if g = 0, **for then** any basis serves as a set of z's.

Does the phrase exist, or should be there the**m** instead?

Comment: _For then_ is not a constituent phrase by itself -- it's two words together. _For_ means 'since, because', and _then_ means 'in that case', so together they mean _Because, in that case,_ (i.e, when g = 0), which is perfectly understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For then** is correct. **For** is an a conjunction approximating to "**because**" and "**then**" is an adverb  = at that point/in that case.

Thus for then ... = because, in that case, ...

**For then** is rather old-fashioned, and is now restricted mainly to religious language:

> It seemed absurd that the universe be infinite, how could it just go on and on forever? It also seemed absurd that it be finite, **for then** there would be a wall, and one could wonder about what was beyond it. (*The Life of the Cosmos*, Lee Smolin 1999).

Comment: Not sure "**for then** is rather old-fashioned, and is now restricted mainly to religious language," but I agree that the OP's usage of **for then** is correct. In my experience, **for then** is not at all uncommon in mathematics. One might read the OP's example as follows: "The result is trivial if g = 0, for *it* then *follows that* any basis serves as a set of z's."

Answer (score -1):

"For then" which can mean interval, while is used in informal writings however there is no clause which indicates the existence of "for then".
Hence with reference to formal writings, it would be suggestive to use "then" instead of "for then".

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: I am surprised to see "for then" being said to mean "interval" - have you any support for that?